# Metro-like full-screen browser using PyQT/PySide

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I've seen sample code that allows one to use PyQT or PySide with QtWebKit to launch a fullscreen browser. I am not familiar with how Qt works. Is it possible to create a web-browser that emulates a Windows 8 Metro-like UI?

I am looking at the following features:

- right clicking anywhere brings up a sliding panel
- hotkey combinations reveal transparent sliding panels

Is this possible?

Short of this, is there a sample PySide code that creates a webbrowser with the corresponding toolbar, url bar, menus, etc ... ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes that seems possible.

To get your application to show fullscreen:

```
mainwindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
mainwindow.showFullScreen()
```

Setting up hotkeys and mouse event handling is definitely possible, there are plenty of tutorials online ([mouse event handling example](http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/pyqt-events/)).

For the Metro-like look, you can set widgets' style using CSS, [examples here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/stylesheet-examples.html).

Comment: Thanks Junuxx, would you know if it possible to overlay some sort of a panel in this fullscreen browser?

Comment: @jett:I haven't used sliding widgets myself, but again, it should be possible. Take a look [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/8955) for a simple example with code.